# New Array Without Explicitly Specifying Data Type

Tags: c#

I just saw this syntax while checking the docs for EF:

```
DropIndex("dbo.MyTable", new[]{"MyColumName"});
```

I was confused for a second before figuring out that it was just shorthand for `new string[]{"MyColumName"}`. I couldn't really find examples of that being valid syntax, so I tried:

```
string[] fooArray = new[] {"SomeString"};
```

The compiler doesn't have a problem with it, I guess since it can absolutely determine the type from the fact that the array is being populated by a string.

I don't see anything about it in the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx) and it doesn't seem to work with int values (I guess because it doesn't know automatically if I am passing `int` or `long` automatically). So, I guess this is just a curiosity, rather than a useful feature.

Anyway, the actual question. Is there any advantage to this syntax, situations where it should be used, and where it should be avoided? Can it be used with numbers somehow?

P.S. I do feel a bit silly asking this, seems like semantics.

Comment: The "docs" you linked are from 2003. Check [Implicitly Typed Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384090.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work for all types provided all items are of the same type or it can know what is the left hand side is or the parameter type is.

Notice it does work for `int`s: https://dotnetfiddle.net/S2DLzV

Answer (score 2):

The advantage of this syntax is the same for any use of `var` -- avoiding duplication in the code and making code changes more quickly. I use this syntax all the time, but where it really saves is when you're writing small numbers of structured, anonymous objects, like this testing example;

```
var tests = new [] {
   new { input="foo", expected = 3 },
   new { input="foobar", expected = 6 },
   new { input="", expected = 0 },
};

foreach(var test in tests) {
    Assert.AreEqual(test.expected, myStringLength(test.input));
}
```